# jQuery .change() not firing?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I've got a jQuery .change() event, to recognise when a radio button is selected / changed.

Here's the radio button code:

```
<input type="radio" name="joint" value="0" class="who" data-entity="me"/>
<input type="radio" name="joint" value="1" class="who" data-entity="me and partner"/>
```

My javascript to detect the change is as such:

```
$('input[name=joint]').bind('change', function(){
    alert('changed');
    $('.jointWho').html('Cover for '+$('option:selected',this).data('entity'));
});
```

However, when I select/change the radio button, the even doesn't fire, and I don't see an alert.

Any ideas?

Comment: What if **next time** you try it on jsfiddle (http://jsfiddle.net/CSa2W/) before ask?

Comment: ..yeah it clearly works

Comment: Is your code within a document ready call, or any on-load call?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem is probably that you lack a document.ready call. If you're attempting to bind things before the HTML is loaded, they appear to go through, but no binding is actually done (because no elements exist if the HTML isn't loaded). So try this, wrap your binding like this.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
  // Your code
})
```

This will ensure that the HTML is completely loaded and that your bindings get applied at the correct time.

Answer (score 0):

It should have been in the onLoad event.